# XSLT/XML: Unwrap value from nesting element

Tags: xml, xslt

Given I have the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-model href="http://www.stoa.org/epidoc/schema/8.19/tei-epidoc.rng"
schematypens="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://www.stoa.org/epidoc/schema/8.19/tei-epidoc.rng"
schematypens="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="tei_poetry_parse2.xslt"?>

<TEI>
    <l>In nova fert animus mutatas dicere formas</l>
    <l>corpora; di, coeptis (nam vos mutastis et illas)</l>
</TEI>
```

which I want to transform to the following code with XSLT

```
<lb /> 
In nova fert animus mutatas dicere formas
<lb /> 
corpora; di, coeptis (nam vos mutastis et illas)
```

So basically I want to extract the text-content and put it after the element (which I want to change to an empty or self-closing `<lb>`.
I tried it with the following XSLT-Stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>


    <xsl:template match="/">
        <text>

            <title>Text</title>

            <xsl:apply-templates/>

        </text>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="l" xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">

        <lb />
        <xsl:value-of select="(text())"/>

    </xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I transform that, all the `<lb>`-tags are nested within each other. When I change the output-method to `html` it works, but I need XML as output.
I would be glad for any help!

What I get:
[DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtO4u.png)

Comment: is this your entire stylesheet?

Comment: "*When I transform that, all the <lb>-tags are nested within each other.*" No, they're not. Please provide a **complete** example that would enable us to reproduce the problem - see: [mcve].

Comment: I'm sorry. I will deliver the full stylesheet and XML:

Comment: And what is the exact - and full - result you want to get out of the given example? -- BTW, applying your stylesheet to the given example does **NOT** produce the output you claim. And it's not clear why you need `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" ` when the input has no namespaces.

Comment: I basically want everything to be the same except the text should be DIVIDED by `<lb />`  tags instead of being WRAPPED by `<l></l>` tags. I use oXygen XML-Editor for transformation and Saxon as Processor

Comment: The stylesheet you presented seems already to work pretty much the way you want, modulo the weird namespace issue.  Are you perhaps confused that no newlines are inserted between the `<lb/>` tags and the text?  Inserting such would constitute a *modification* of the text, but if that's what you're after then please clarify the question in that regard.  In any case, the `<lb>` elements in the output are *not* nested within each other.

Comment: I guess it's possible that your XSLT implementation or (more likely) the application with which you are examining the result is broken or misconfigured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us have a simple working example:

**XML**

```
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" >
    <l>In nova fert animus mutatas dicere formas</l>
    <l>corpora; di, coeptis (nam vos mutastis et illas)</l>
</TEI>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xpath-default-namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" >
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/TEI">
    <text>
        <title>Text</title>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="l">
    <lb/>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<text>
   <title>Text</title>
    <lb/>In nova fert animus mutatas dicere formas
    <lb/>corpora; di, coeptis (nam vos mutastis et illas)
</text>
```

---

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/a9Gixb

Comment: It really seems to be a problem of my application. Thank you anyways for your answer!

Comment: It does require an XSLT 2.0 processor. If your application uses XSLT 1.0 , you will need to use a prefix instead of `xpath-default-namespace`.